# Python (problems with scipy.optimize.curve_fit)

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

so I'm having trouble with this piece of code here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sy
import pylab as plb

def oscDecay(x, A, B, C, tau, omega):
    return A*(1+B*np.cos(omega*x))*np.exp(-1*x**2/(2*tau**2))+C


def LMfit(func, x, y, p0, sig):
    #Fits data to non-linear curve using Levenberg-Marquart Method
    #Inputs: func = the function you are fitting data to
    #        x, y = data set
    #       p0 = tuple containing inital guesses for fitting  parameters
    #       sig = uncertainty in values
    #Outputs: nlfit = array containing optimal values for fitting parameters
    #       nlcov = two dimensional array (square root of diagonals contain
    #               uncertainty in fitting parameters)
    nlfit, nlpcov = sy.optimize.curve_fit(func, x, y, p0, sig)
    return nlfit, nlpcov

data=np.loadtxt('testing.txt', skiprows=4)

x=data[:, 0]
y=data[:, 1]
sig=data[:, 2]

#intial parameters
A0=16.5
B0=0.57
C0=17
tau0=30
omega0=7
p0=(A0, B0, C0, tau0, omega0)

nlfit, nlpcov = LMfit(oscDecay, x, y, p0, sig)
```

When I try to run it, I get this error message:

nlfit, nlpcov = sy.optimize.curve_fit(oscDecay, x, y, p0, sig). 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'optimize'

I'm not sure what it means since my software provided me with scipy.optimize already to use.

Comment: You need to do `import scipy.optimize`, not just `import scipy`.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the import seems to not have worked as noted by the commenter. 
I had to make a synthetic sample to test your code. I just left out the sigmas and it worked all right (using Ipython notebooks).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
from scipy import optimize as opt
%matplotlib inline

def oscDecay(x, A, B, C, tau, omega):
    return A*(1+B*np.cos(omega*x))*np.exp(-1*x**2/(2*tau**2))+C

# make an example of data with some experimental noise
def oscDecayexp(x, A, B, C, tau, omega):
    rand=np.random.rand(len(x))
    return A*(1+(B+rand/10)*np.cos(omega*x))*np.exp(-1*x**2/(2*tau**2))+C


def LMfit(func, x, y, p0 ,sig=None):
    #Fits data to non-linear curve using Levenberg-Marquart Method
    #Inputs: func = the function you are fitting data to
    #        x, y = data set
    #       p0 = tuple containing inital guesses for fitting  parameters
    #       sig = uncertainty in values
    #Outputs: nlfit = array containing optimal values for fitting parameters
    #       nlcov = two dimensional array (square root of diagonals contain
    #               uncertainty in fitting parameters)
    nlfit, nlpcov = opt.curve_fit(func, x, y, p0, sig)
    return nlfit, nlpcov


#intial parameters
A0=16.5
B0=0.57
C0=17
tau0=30
omega0=7

x=np.arange(0,80,0.02)
y=oscDecayexp(x,A0,B0,C0,tau0,omega0)

p.figure(figsize=(12,8))

p.plot(x, oscDecay(x,A0,B0,C0,tau0,omega0)) # blue
p.plot(x, oscDecayexp(x,A0,B0,C0,tau0,omega0),lw=0.5) #green

p0=(A0, B0, C0, tau0, omega0)
# scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, absolute_sigma=False, check_finite=True, **kw)  
nlfit, nlpcov = LMfit(oscDecay, x, y, p0 )

print nlfit
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `from scipy import optimize as opt` does the trick. upvoted :)

Comment: @ Joe: +1 as well helped me, though it is a strange behavior, but exactly such a trick helped in [simple example](https://github.com/scipy-lectures/scientific-python-lectures/blob/main/intro/scipy/examples/plot_curve_fit.py)... though no problems at https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/welcome.ipynb at all with such a code